# Does Adafruit PowerBoost 1000 Charger support data transfer?

Tags: usb, adafruit, charging

As the title says - Does [Adafruit PowerBoost 1000 Charger](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2465#technical-details) support data transfer?
I mean that if I connect USB on one side to PC and Arduino on other side - can I still program it and get serial monitor communication?
Are the data lines connected??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it doesn't.

As you can see from [the schematic](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-powerboost-1000c-load-share-usb-charge-boost/downloads) the incoming data lines aren't connected, and the outgoing are wired through appropriate resistors to set the current availability.